# Invariants/monovariants: numbers on a board

Tags: combinatorics, invariance

The numbers from $1$ through $2008$ are written on a blackboard. Every second, Dr. Math erases four numbers of the form $a, b, c, a+b+c$, and replaces them with the numbers $a+b, b+c, c+a$.

Prove that this can continue for at most $10$ minutes.

Comment: What did you try? What direction you investigate? You need to define when the process stops... when you get 3 numbers? if not will always continue for at least 10 minutes. it will take 2005 seconds... to get to 3 numbers.

Comment: @Moti: Clearly it stops when there is no longer a number on the board that is the sum of three other numbers on the board.

Comment: You are right:) my careless view...

Comment: @Abhinandan The posted solution looks right to me. If you do not understand it, please clarify what is confusing to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Observe that both the sum of the numbers and the sum of their squares is invariant under the process. Let $n=2008$.

Let $m$ be the number of integers on the board.

Then by Cauchy-Schwarz, we have $\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \geq \dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4m}$, i.e.
$m \geq \dfrac{3n(n+1)}{2(2n+1)}$ and hence the number of times the process can continue is at most $n-m\leq\dfrac{n^2-n}{2(2n+1)}$ which is less than 502 for $n=2008$.